# How to create a global array variable in xslt 1.0 and dynamically set the values to it on looping

Tags: arrays, xslt

Hi i need to create a global array variable and set values to it dynamically on looping thru fro-each

I tried like below

```
<xsl:key name="kItemValue" match="/*/*/*/accountId/text()" use="."/>
 <xsl:variable name="AccountIds"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/accountId/text()[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kItemValue', .)[1])]">
<xsl:variable name="AccountIds"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:variable>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

latter I need to iterate through that array values, such that on every loop it checks a value with current loop item  and print some text. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no "arrays" in XSLT and you can't change the values of a "global" variable that has been set. - Perhaps you describe your *problem* without asking how to achieve what isn't possible technically.

Comment: And where is "Java"? I've removed the tag.

Comment: @ laune when I do for-each I get some values, those needs to be stored in a variable latter I need to iterate through that values where I do a check of value based on that I will print text, this is my problem. for eg on iteration I got some value 3 5 6 7 2..like that I need to store these values to a variable. latter I need to iterate through these values and say if value>3 i will print "just pass" , if value >5 "pass" like that any idea to achieve this using XSLT 1.0

Comment: You haven't described your problem, you've described the way that you would solve your problem in a procedural language. It's very difficult to reverse engineer your requirements from such a description. Please describe the transformation you want to perform: input, output, and how they relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, because (as was already mentioned in the comments) there are no arrays in XML. However, if you want, you could populate a variable with a set of selected nodes, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="unique-accounts" select="/*/*/*/accountId[generate-id()=generate-id(key('account-by-id', .)[1])]"/>
```

and, at some later point, process these nodes, for example as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$unique-accounts">
    <!-- do something -->   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that for this to work, the variable must store a **node-set**, not a bunch of text values - so your key in this example would have to be modified to:

```
<xsl:key name="account-by-id" match="accountId" use="." />
```